# Open a video within the app with sound even if it is in silent mode

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I want to know how can I open a video within an app using react native, and it to work with sounds, even though the phone is on silent mode

I want to know how can I open a video within an app using react native, and it to work with sounds, even though the phone is on silent mode, just on Ios devices.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We need to see what you already tried to do. This site is for programming help, **not to provide code according to a set of task requirements**. Please retake the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and visit the [How to Ask pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Opa, eaí Marcelo! Não entendi, não posso pedir uma sugestão? No caso eu não tentei nada, por que não tenho ideia de como fazer. Não estou pedindo código, estou perguntando qual caminho seguir. Abraço!

Comment: Davi, take a look on [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason) please. After that, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#Search,%20and%20Research).

Comment: Acho que você tá errado, de qualquer forma. Minha pergunta foi simples.